Azure API Management policy for loop not working on array
In Azure API Management I have a SOAP to REST api with the wsdl imported. I am able to send requests through however the liquid template in the set-body which creates the XML request from JSON is not able to read an array in the JSON.
Liquid Template:
<set-body template="liquid">
            <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                <soap:Body>
                    <testEndpointName>
                        <request>
                            <Attachments>
                                {% for item in body.testEndpointName.request.attachments %}
                                <testEndpointNameAttachment>
                                    {% if item.fileBytes %}
                                    <FileBytes>{{item.fileBytes}}</FileBytes>
                                    {% else %}
                                    <FileBytes xsi:nil="true" />
                                    {% endif %}
                                    {% if item.fileName %}
                                    <FileName>{{item.fileName}}</FileName>
                                    {% else %}
                                    <FileName xsi:nil="true" />
                                    {% endif %}
                                    {% if item.fileSize %}
                                    <FileSize >{{item.fileSize}}</FileSize>
                                    {% else %}
                                    <FileSize xsi:nil="true" />
                                    {% endif %}
                                </testEndpointNameAttachment>
                                {% endfor %}
                            </Attachments>
                            {% if body.testEndpointName.request.email %}
                            <Email>{{body.testEndpointName.request.email}}</Email>
                            {% else %}
                            <Email xsi:nil="true" />
                            {% endif %}
                            {% if body.testEndpointName.request.emailBody %}
                            <EmailBody">{{body.testEndpointName.request.emailBody}}</EmailBody>
                            {% else %}
                            <EmailBody xsi:nil="true" />
                            {% endif %}
                            {% if body.testEndpointName.request.policyNumber %}
                            <PolicyNumber>{{body.testEndpointName.request.policyNumber}}</PolicyNumber>
                            {% else %}
                            <PolicyNumberxsi:nil="true" />
                            {% endif %}
                            {% if body.testEndpointName.request.subject %}
                            <Subject>{{body.testEndpointName.request.subject}}</Subject>
                            {% else %}
                            <Subject xsi:nil="true" />
                            {% endif %}
                        </request>
                    </testEndpointName>
                </soap:Body>
            </soap:Envelope>
        </set-body>

Example Input:
{
    "testEndpointName": {
        "request": {
            "attachments": [
                {
                    "fileBytes": "fakebytes",
                    "fileName": "fakename.txt",
                    "fileSize": "1234"
                }
            ],
            "email": "testemail@test.com",
            "emailBody": "test email body",
            "policyNumber": "1234",
            "subject": "test subject"
        }
    }
}

This gets me a request which looks like the following:
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Body>
      <testEndpointName>
         <request>
            <Attachments></Attachments>
            <Email>testemail@test.com</Email>
            <EmailBody>test email body</EmailBody>
            <PolicyNumber>1234</PolicyNumber>
            <Subject>test subject</Subject>
         </request>
      </testEndpointName>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>

The Attachments section is always empty. I have tried replacing for with JSONArrayFor and also made sure that the header Content-Type is always set to application/json. I also tried hard coding values inside the for loop to see if it ever got in there and it did not.
Any help would be appreciated.

The code is case sensitive.

Where is the case off? It looks correct to me.

attachments and 

I believe that it is correct case wise for those statements. The "for item in body.testEndpointName.request.attachments" corresponds to the json input which has a lowercase attachments and the  tag is for the xml output where it is also correct in the output.

Before doing the liquid-transformation, it has to be ensured that the Content-Type is set to application/json, like the input data.
This can also be done in the request itself, but to be on the safe side, it can be set in the policy.
The response Content-Type application/xml has to be set after the transformation.
Policy:
<set-header name="Content-Type" exists-action="override">
    <value>application/json</value>
</set-header>
<set-body template="liquid">
    <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <soap:Body>
            <testEndpointName>
                <request>
                    <Attachments>
                                {% for item in body.testEndpointName.request.attachments %}
                                <testEndpointNameAttachment>
                                    {% if item.fileBytes %}
                                    <FileBytes>{{item.fileBytes}}</FileBytes>
                                    {% else %}
                                    <FileBytes xsi:nil="true" />
                                    {% endif %}
                                    {% if item.fileName %}
                                    <FileName>{{item.fileName}}</FileName>
                                    {% else %}
                                    <FileName xsi:nil="true" />
                                    {% endif %}
                                    {% if item.fileSize %}
                                    <FileSize>{{item.fileSize}}</FileSize>
                                    {% else %}
                                    <FileSize xsi:nil="true" />
                                    {% endif %}
                                </testEndpointNameAttachment>
                                {% endfor %}
                    </Attachments>
                </request>
            </testEndpointName>
        </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>
</set-body>
<set-header name="Content-Type" exists-action="override">
    <value>application/xml</value>
</set-header>


Test in APIM:


I had the header being set however the response Content-Type was being set to text/xml in mine. When I update it to application/xml I start receiving a 415 Unsupported Media Type: "The error response body was not a valid SOAP error response. The response body was empty." from apim. Curious that it works on yours, I will investigate further.

I'm hitting the same issue, even after setting the content type to application/JSON in the request and application/XML after the transformation. Could you let me know if you were able to fix the issue?

Any suggestions on this issue?
